# How to load label data presented in raster format into Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network

I would like to use a CNN network to segment 2 objects (binary: "0: object not present 1: object present") into shapes, but I have an issue with data. The training data is 150 images and in "jpg" format and the ground truth (label data) is also 150 images of "png" rasters of 0 and 1
(resulting in black white images...)

Now, the question is how to load this hybrid of train images and label images in keras/tensorflow and if there`s a dummy example and/or demonstration on how to do that in python, I would be grateful.